# Perl CGI: mix URL and Body parameters

Tags: perl, http, cgi

I try to have a POST-request to a Perl CGI. All is fine if I have pure GET or pure POST.

```
my $q = CGI->new ();
my $method = $q->request_method ();
my $p1 = $q->param ("p1");
my $p2 = $q->param ("p2");
```

But when I mix URL-parameters with Body-parameters I do not get the URL-parameter with the POST-request. It is transferred correctly if I check what the browser sent.

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/test/?p1=abc">
<input type="text" name="p2" value="xyz"/>
<input type="submit"/></br>
</form>
```

Is it not possible to mix both?

Comment: Well you should not do it. What is your rationale of doing so? Why not just use form fields to achieve the same? What you try to do will work only with [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) method (it assumes parameters passed through `URL` . [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) method encodes form data very different way.

Comment: Perhaps your should familiarize with following [webpage](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq9). And please read [Why not to use CGI](https://www.perl.com/article/perl-and-cgi/) if you want to avoid many pitfalls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CGI` has `url_param` for interrogating query parameters separately from POST fields.

This even provides some flexibility for deciding what-overrides-what in your code:

```perl
# URL parameter overrides POST field
my $p1 = $q->url_param('p1') // $q->param('p1');
# POST field overrides URL parameter
my $p2 = $q->param('p2') // $q->url_param('p2');
```

**Note:** `//` is a Perl operator for an "undef coalesce" introduced in v5.10. It's available even without `use v5.10`.